# Comparing 2 lists in .net for multiple matching elements Linq

Tags: .net, list, entity-framework

In .net if I have 2 lists

```
ListA 
{ID : 1, Value : "foo"}, 
{ID : 2, Value : "bar"}, 
{ID : 3, Value : "zoo"}

ListB 
{ID : 1, ListA_Id : 1, Value "bar"}, 
{ID : 2, ListA_Id : 3, Value "zoo"}, 
{ID : 3, ListA_Id : 4, Value "foo"}
```

If I want to search List B for all elements whose ListA_Id field matches Ids in List A I can do this:

```
ListB.Where(x => listA.ID.Contains(x.ListA_Id)).ToList()
```

But what if I want to make sure that both values from ListA match ListB?

e.g `ListA.Id == ListB.ListA_Id && ListA.Value = ListB.Value`

The third element in ListA would match the second Element in listB in the above example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Any` extension method and specify your condition as a predicate:

```
listB.Where(b => listA.Any(a => a.ID == b.ListA_Id && a.Value == b.Value)).ToList();
```

This would only be suitable for situations where the lists contain small numbers of elements. As the lists grow larger, this will become exponentially slower, since you may end up checking all elements of `listA` for each element of `listB`. In such cases, it may be worthwhile converting `listA` into a dictionary for faster lookups:

```
var dictA = listA.ToDictionary(a => a.ID);
var result = listB
    .Where(b => dictA.TryGetValue(b.ListA_Id, out var a) && a.Value == b.Value))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Great. Thank you.